# Software Serial blocking Wifi Connection

Tags: nodemcu, softwareserial

I'm trying to connect my NodeMCU to wifi. It isn't finishing because software serial is interrupting it.

Sort of like [Software serial conflict with WiFi on ESP8266](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/60175/software-serial-conflict-with-wifi-on-esp8266).

Here's my code:

```c#
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"

const char* ssid     = "mywifi";
const char* password = "password123";

void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);
        Serial.println("");

        connectWifi();

        SoftwareSerial pinSerial(1, 3);
        pinSerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // send data received from serial port
}

// in separate function so I can reconnect in the loop 
bool connectWifi() {
        WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
                delay(500);
                Serial.print(".");
        }
        Serial.println("");
        Serial.println("WiFi connected");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        if( WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
                return true;
        } else {
                Serial.println("wifi connection failed");
        }
}
```

The console outputs the periods as it's connecting but never prints the IP and instead prints the serial data it received while trying to connect.

Can I delay the activation of the software serial port? Should I use another serial library?

Please don't focus on basic code errors, I'm still learning.

Comment: you start SoftwareSerial on pins of the hardware serial.

Comment: oh you're right! how do I read and write to the hardware pins, not the usb port?

Comment: the USB chip of NodeMcu is wired to pins io 1 and io 3 of the esp8266 and you write and read it over `Serial`

Comment: `SoftwareSerial pinSerial(1, 3);` in `setup()` is strange as it 1) uses the hardware serial pins, 2) is never used other than `begin()`, and 3) is destructed when returning. What are you trying to do exactly?